# unable to display urls in table @ masterViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift, nsurl

[image]

I'm not able to compile the code in masterViewController as

I'm receiving an error `UITableView` does not have member named `textLabel`

```
var urls = [NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/03_GURU_JI_TERI_REHMAT_Singer_Sada_Thakur.mp3")!]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
    cell.textLabe!.text = NSURL(string: urls)[indexPath.row] // error UITableView does not have member named textLabel
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is missing an l at the end

Comment: urls[indexPath.row].path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are written

```
cell.textLabe!.text
```

you have to write

```
cell.textLabel!.text
```

To print url string in textLabel

```
cell.textLabel!.text = urls[indexPath.row].absoluteString!
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I can not do! I have less reputation. Please do it. Thanks

Comment: I would have wore my spectacles but the issue is there i.e

Comment: three error I'm receiving                                                                                  * Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSURL' that accepts an argument list of type '(string:NSURL])                                                                                  * Cannot subscript a value of type <<error type>> with an index of type 'int'

Comment: Ok, You have already converted the string to urls in the `var urls` and you are converting again it into the url !! you have to write just text in the table cell. @SabhaySardana

Comment: @SabhaySardana I think you are new in swift. Edited the answer.

Comment: Ashish is there any way to remove meta data and display only the name of the file            cell.textLabel!.text = urls[indexPath.row].absoluteString!   // editing in this code only ?

Comment: you can use the `cell.textLabel!.text = urls[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent!` @SabhaySardana

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var urls = [NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/03_GURU_JI_TERI_REHMAT_Singer_Sada_Thakur.mp3")!]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
cell.textLabe!.text = urls[indexPath.row]
return cell
}
```